# Why is "sensor fusion" without "the"?

Tags: articles

I'm writing an academic article and using a phrase "sensor fusion". Whenever I Google this phrase it is without "the", what I personally intend to use. The only explanation I [found](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/) is that some common types of nouns don't take an article; such as the names of academic subjects: mathematics, biology, history, computer science. But "sensor fusion" is rather a method in an engineering instead of an academic subject.

What is the explanation for omitting "the"?

My original sentence as a reply to the reviewer:
"A better implication of the sensor fusion was indicated through the paper"

(In my original language I don't use articles and it is my biggest problem in English.)

Comment: If you say "the sensor fusion", you are talking about a particular instance of sensor fusion. If you say "sensor fusion", you are talking about the phenomenon of sensor fusion in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a scientist, but I think I can help you with the difference between using *sensor fusion* with *the* and using it without an article.

If you are talking about the methodology *sensor fusion* in a **general way,** you should not use *the.*  Here are a few simple example sentences:

> *Sensor fusion* is the best methodology to use.
>
> The methodology I would recommend the most is *sensor fusion*.

However, if, for example, you pair *sensor fusion* with another noun, such as *approach, methodology* or *experiment,* and are talking about one of these in a specific way,  it would be correct to write sentences like these:

> We tried *sensor fusion* and data integration, but only the sensor fusion approach worked.
>
> Experiments using *the sensor fusion methodology* showed positive results.
>
> *The sensor fusion* experiments were successful, but the data integration experiments were not.

When I consider your sentence *"A better implication of the sensor fusion was indicated through the paper"*, first of all, the correct preposition to use would be *throughout,* not *through,* and I do not have enough information to decide whether you need the article *the,* but I think that if you are talking about *sensor fusion* in a specific way, it would be clearer to pair it with another noun, as in the examples I have provided above; also, the meanings of the noun *implication* and the passive verb *implicated* are not clear to me.

However, I would suggest that my distinction between (1) using *sensor fusion* in a general way (no article) and (2) when paired with another noun and used in a specific way, might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you. Great reply. 
My reviewer writes: "None of the papers do focus on advances in such a “fusion” research area." I understand that in this case I would use "the" as I reply to the reviewer's comment. 
In general you helped me to see why I can't google "the sensor fusion" and where was a flow in my thinking. Thanks

Comment: I believe that in "... but only the sensor fusion approach worked" the *the* is there for the *approach* not *sensor fusion*. You could say, "but only sensor fusion worked", just as you'd say, "but only the first approach worked".

Comment: I might add that 'the sensor fusion' without pairing it with a noun is actually valid English, but instead means *'the act of fusing some sensors'*. One might say, for example, *'The data integration went great, but we blew up our laboratory during the sensor fusion.'*

Answer (score 10):

We do not ordinarily use an article with the name of a process or common event, except to designate a specific instance.

Allow me to illustrate using a process I understand, *elision*, instead of one I don’t, so I may avoid ignorant and irrelevant statements about *sensor fusion*.

> *Elision* means eliminating some sounds from a word in specific phonetic or metrical contexts.
>   *Elision* is very frequent in Shakespeare’s verse.

In both of these statements we are speaking of the general phenomenon, and therefore do not use an article.

> In the line *Woo't weep? Woo't fight? Woo't fast? Woo't tear thyself?*, the meter requires elision of *wouldest thou* to *woo't*.

Here we still do not use the article, because we are speaking of bringing the general phenomenon to bear on a specific case.

> The elisions in *Woo't weep? Woo't fight? Woo't fast? Woo't tear thyself?* throws a heavier emphasis on the verbs *weep, fight, fast, tear*.

Here we are talking of specific, realized instances of the phenomenon, and consequently we employ the article.

Comment: Elision is applied to 'phonetic and metrical contexts'. I do not think a scientific paper would be written in a meter. The real question here is when to use and when not to use the article, not to make it fit in a meter.

Comment: @sanchises I believe you mistake what I'm saying. The relevant article is the one present or absent before the word *elision*, a standin for *sensor fusion*, not the one in the quotation which is elided. But I will replace my example so this is less confusing.

Comment: Oh yes, I would have seem to misread you a little. Excuse me :)

Comment: @sanchises Not at all; it's my fault, my original example was confusing.